# Pyqrcode won't work with Flask Blueprints

Tags: python, flask

I have just started study python and flask. My question may seems simple or stupid, but I'm really in deadlock condition. I can't study further without understanding current code behaviour.
Here is my question. 

I've very strange code behaviour in my project. One of my training flask.app generate qr-code from user input. After generate code, user has options: get link on png or direct download file. This app works well.

Later, I have decided to make blueprint set from my small training apps, the first was qr-generator. I've just copied function of qr-gen route, but it doesn't work well - qr can't save png, I've received error, after click on button get link or download:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'tmp/201612131254.png'

Here is hierarchy:

```
├── app.py
├── blueprints
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── qr_generator
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── macros
│   │   │   │   └── render_field.html
│   │   │   └── qr_request.html
│   │   ├── tmp
│   │   └── view.py
│   └── tmp
├── config.py
├── static
├── templates
│   └── _base_template.html
├── tmp
└── views.py
```

Here is **app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import config
from blueprints.qr_generator.view import qr_view

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config)

app.register_blueprint(qr_view)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template(
        '_base_template.html'
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Blueprint qr-generator **view.py**:

```
import datetime
from flask import Blueprint, request, render_template, send_from_directory, redirect
from pyqrcode import QRCode
from blueprints.qr_generator.forms import UserTextField

# Blueprint
qr_view = Blueprint('qr_view', __name__, template_folder='templates')

# Views:
@qr_view.route('/qr_view', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def qr_generator():
    qr_file_name = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserTextField(request.form)
        if form.validate():
            qr_code = QRCode(form.data['text'], encoding='utf-8')
            qr_file_name = 'tmp/' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') + '.png'
            qr_code.png(qr_file_name, scale=5)
            if form.data['mode'] == 'download':
                return redirect(qr_file_name)
    else:
        form = UserTextField()

    return render_template(
        'qr_request.html',
        form=form,
        link=qr_file_name,
    )


@qr_view.route('/tmp/<path:qr_path>')
def show_qr(qr_path):
    return send_from_directory('tmp', qr_path, as_attachment=True)
```

**qr_request.html**:

```
{% extends '_base_template.html' %}<html lang="en">
{% block content %}
    <div class="content">
        {% from "macros/render_field.html" import render_field %}
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('qr_view.qr_generator') }}">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <dl>
                {% for field in form %}
                    {% if field.id != 'csrf_token' %}
                        {{ render_field(field) }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                </dl>
                <input type="submit" value="{{ 'Submit' }}" class="btn">
         </form>

        <div class="link">
        {%  if link %}
             <p>Your QRCode is <a href="{{ link }}">here</p>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The same code work well without Blueprint...
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to make sure, that your path to the file is correct. I usually set a `BASEPATH` in my configuration that is absolute to the application directory, so I always get the correct path to the qr-code.

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
QRCODE_FOLDER = os.path.join(basedir, "blueprints/qr_generator/tmp/")
```

Other option would be to have your rout return an image on the fly, without saving it to disk.

Something like this (from application of mine):

```
@app.route('/parts/qrcode/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def generate_qrcode(id):
     part = Part.query.get(id)
     data = "flaskparts://%i" % part.id
     qr = qrcode.QRCode(
         version=1,
         error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
         box_size=10,
         border=4
     )
     qr.add_data(data)
     qr.make(fit=True)
     img = qr.make_image()
     img_io = StringIO.StringIO()
     img.save(img_io, 'PNG')
     img_io.seek(0)
     response = make_response(img_io.read())
     response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
     response.headers['Content-Description'] = 'attachment; filename=%i.png' % id
     return response
```

Comment: Seems that problem was in pycharm..if I launch app by console, QR save png in /tmp and user can download it. According to Blueprints concept I would like to save png files inside blueprint **qr_generator**. When I change code -   `qr_file_name = 'blueprints/qr_generator/tmp/' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') + '.png'` I get new file into folder `blueprints/qr_generator/tmp/` but user can't get qr-code - file not found `http://127.0.0.1:5000/blueprints/qr_generator/tmp/201612131800.png`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the absolute path of the file. Try the following code to create the file path

```
os.path.abspath('tmp/' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') + '.png')
```

Comment: If I specify the absolute path, user gets abspath in a browser and still can't download qr-code.